# Dividing a raw table into sub tables before normalization?

Tags: database, database-design, many-to-many, database-normalization

I have a raw table having 28 columns and around 300 rows that I want to normalize. I wonder whether I should divide the table into sub tables based on entity characteristics in advance before normalization.

Also, should I figure out relationship (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many) between each sub table before normalization? As far as I know, I have to make something called junction table for many-to-many relationship. I am confused about the procedure of designing a database given a single raw table. I appreciate your comments. Thank you.

Comment: Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by others that join back to it that have fewer problems of a certain kind. Normalizing a wrong design gives you another wrong design. A table that is the join of other tables in general cannot record all of what the individual tables collectively record. So if you need the individual tables you should normalize them not the original. First get a correct design then normalize. Also you don't seem to know what you are doing. Please explain where you got this assignment, show your work following a design textbook & ask re the 1st place you are stuck.

Comment: I am doing it for my own project. I cannot upload what I am working on to here, so I want to make a simple example. Let's say I want to design a database for animals living in different zoos. Columns for this table can be AnimalName, AnimalSpecies, AnimalGender, AnimalAge, ZooName, ZooLocation. I can divide that table into two, one having name, species, gender, age and the other having zoo name and zoo location. I am wondering whether this division belongs to normalization process like 1NF and 2NF.

Comment: Please clarify via edits not comments. But you are just asking us to rewrite a textbook on design. And if you don't know how to normalize then you are just asking us to rewrite a textbook on normalization. Both are too broad--[ask]. Go to a presentation & ask just 1 question re where you are 1st stuck. PS I said, you need a correct design before normalizing. You must tell us what you need to record & what your tables record. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.